# Rails is there any other way of doing this loop? DRY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Rails is know for keeping things DRY.

I am going to create a table like this: http://www.duoh.com/csstutorials/tablesv2/

Is there any other way of doing repeated loops?

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th class="column1" scope="row">Data usage</th>

<%= @something.each do |info| %>
        <td><%= info.name %></td>
<% end %>
    </tr>   
     <tr class="odd">
        <th class="column1" scope="row">Opslag Capaciteit</th>

<%= @something.each do |info| %>
<td><%= info.price %></td>
<% end %>
    </tr>   
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using HAML would DRY it up a lot:

```
%tbody
  %tr
    %th.column1{:scope=>"row"} Data usage
    -@something.each do |info|
      %td= info.name
  %tr.odd
    %th.column1{:scope=>"row"} Opslag Capaciteit
    -@something.each do |info|
      %td= info.price
```

**Sorry if the code below doesn't work.  It is complicated and I have not tested it.**

If you really want to make it even simpler, then you can put a helper function in `ApplicationHelper` (or any other helper module that is available in this view) like this:

```
def my_row(name, &block)
  @row_count ||= -1
  @row_count += 1
  row_contents = content_tag(:th, name, :class=>'column1', :scope=>'row')
  @something.each do |item|
    row_contents += content_tag(:td, capture(item, &block))
  end
  content_tag(:tr, row_contents, :class => @row_count.even? ? 'even' : 'odd')
end
```

Then in your view just do:

```
%tbody
  =my_row "Data Usage" do |item|
    =item.name
  =my_row "Opslag Capaciteit" do |item|
    =item.price
```

or in ERB I think that would be:

```
<tbody>
  <%= my_row "Data Usage" do |item| %> <%= item.name %> <% end %>
  <%= my_row "Opslag Capaciteit" do |item| %> <%= item.price %> <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Abstracting functionality is precisely the purpose of ruby's block/yield structure.

In a helper:

```
def tds list
  list.map do |item|
    content_tag :td, yield(item)
  end.join("\n")
end
```

Then in your view:

```
<%= tds @something {|i| i.name } %>

<!-- other stuff -->

<%= tds @something {|i| i.price } %>
```