# In Rails is there a better way to iterate over this structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iteration, haml

This is basically what I'm trying to do, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it with out running the loop twice?

```
%table
  %thead
    %tr
      - @widgets.each do |widget|
        %th
          = widget.name
  %tbody
    %tr
      - @widgets.each do |widget|
        %td
          = widget.info
```

Comment: That's a fairly common pattern. Even if you pre-collected the @widget info, you'd be just moving the problem to another data structure then doing the two iterations again. The collection is relatively small, so it's not a time burden. I suppose if you were clever you could write one `inject` which could accumulate both your head tr row and your body tr row, but it would be more complex than what you have. I'm always running into these cases, too, wishing HTML had a way to define tables by column rather than by row. ;)

Comment: I guess no. there is a possible duplicate question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974462

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is a (perfectly fine) mismatch between your presentation structure and your data structure. Your data structure is a collection of objects with two attributes in play, but your presentation structure contains a collection of the first attribute and a collection of the second attribute.

Don't worry. ActiveRecord caches objects, so `widget` is not database queried again in the second iteration.